# MySQL workbench deleted stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench and have had the following issue happen a number of times to me now.

If I'm altering a Stored Procedure, and workbench freezes or I need to restart workbench for whatever reason, then *sometimes* when I connect back to my DB, the stored procedure no longer exists.

I'm in Workbench 8.0.19 but same has happened in earlier versions as well.

Anyone have an idea why, or more importantly how to avert such happening?

Comment: It will drop the procedure before creating.  A lot of other databases allow "create or replace" which will stop your issue but MySQL doesn't.  It's hard to say how to stop this, all I could say is do the alterations out of hours if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I understand it drops before it recreates, however thats not my problem.
What is happening (it seems). Right Click the sp name, select Alter Stored Procedure.  So I have the tab open to edit it.  I may not do anything and not hit the Apply button (to drop and recreate).  Now if the System crashes or whatever, when I restart workbench sometimes the proc has gone, so appears it has run its own DROP somehow.  I cant replicate the issue consitently (and dont want to).